# Unity tutorial sync var not working

Tags: unity, multiplayer

I tried to make a simple miltiplayer game with the unity [tutorial](https://unity3d.com/de/learn/tutorials/s/multiplayer-networking). The Code of the Player looks like this:

```
 using System.Collections;
 using System.Collections.Generic;
 using UnityEngine;
 using UnityEngine.Networking;

 public class PlayerController : NetworkBehaviour {

     public GameObject bulletPrefab;
     public Transform bulletSpawn;

     public Camera cam;

      // Update is called once per frame
     void Update () {
         if (!isLocalPlayer) {
             return;
         }

         float x = Input.GetAxis ("Horizontal") * Time.deltaTime * 150.0f;
         float z = Input.GetAxis ("Vertical") * Time.deltaTime * 3.0f;
         transform.Rotate (0, x, 0);
         transform.Translate (0, 0, z);


         if(Input.GetKeyDown(KeyCode.Space)){
             CmdFire();
         }

     }

     void Start()
     {
         cam.gameObject.SetActive(false);
         if(isLocalPlayer)
         {
             cam.gameObject.SetActive(true);
         }

     }

     [Command]
     public void CmdFire(){
         GameObject bullet = (GameObject)Instantiate (bulletPrefab, bulletSpawn.position, bulletSpawn.rotation);
         bullet.GetComponent<Rigidbody> ().velocity = bullet.transform.forward * 6.0f;

         // Spawn the bullet on the client
         NetworkServer.Spawn(bullet);

         Destroy (bullet, 2f);
     }


     public override void OnStartLocalPlayer ()
     {
         GetComponent<MeshRenderer> ().material.color = Color.blue;
     }
 }
```

The Code of the health class like this :

```
 using System.Collections;
 using System.Collections.Generic;
 using UnityEngine;
 using UnityEngine.UI;
 using UnityEngine.Networking;

 public class Health : NetworkBehaviour {

     public const int maxHeath = 100;
     [SyncVar(hook="OnChangeHealth")] public int currentHealth  = maxHeath;

     public RectTransform healthBar;
     public RectTransform publicHealthBar;

     private int maxHealthBarSize;

     public bool destroyOnDeath;

     private NetworkStartPosition[] spawnPoints;

     void Start(){
         if (isLocalPlayer) {
             spawnPoints = FindObjectsOfType <NetworkStartPosition>();

             maxHealthBarSize = (int) healthBar.sizeDelta.x;
         }
     }

     public void TakeDamage(int amount){

         if (!isServer) {
             return;
         }

         currentHealth -= amount;

         if (currentHealth <= 0) {

             if (destroyOnDeath) {
                 Destroy (gameObject);
             } 
             else {
                 currentHealth = maxHeath;
                 RpcRespawn ();
             }

         }

     }

     void OnChangeHealth(int health){
         if(isLocalPlayer)
         {
             healthBar.sizeDelta = new Vector2(((float)health / maxHeath) * maxHealthBarSize, healthBar.sizeDelta.y);
         }
     }

     [ClientRpc]
     void RpcRespawn(){
         if (isLocalPlayer) {

             Vector3 spawnPoint = Vector3.zero;
             if (spawnPoints != null && spawnPoints.Length > 0) {
                 spawnPoint = spawnPoints [ Random.Range (0, spawnPoints.Length) ].transform.position;
             }

             transform.position = spawnPoint;
          }
     }

 }
```

But the health bar is only updating on 1 client. This means : A shoots B -> B's Healthbar updates -> B shoots A -> A's healthbar doesn't update.Does anyone know howw to fix the issue? (Is it unity or me?) Probably me :)

Answer (score -1):

I don't fully understand the code here but it doesn't seem that you are doing anything if the player is not local...

```
void OnChangeHealth(int health){
     if(isLocalPlayer)
     {
         healthBar.sizeDelta = new Vector2(((float)health / maxHeath) * maxHealthBarSize, healthBar.sizeDelta.y);
     }
 }
```

Should you not be calling something or whatever to update the other client(s)?

Comment: Even I have been taking a few lesson and of [unity tutorial](https://hackr.io/tutorials/learn-unity). I am relatively new when it comes to using the Unity 3D engine and also new at coding. @Stese: What do you mean if the player is not local? I don't understand the context completely.

Comment: @ Ethan Scott - It's a multiplayer game. The section I've highlighted states :- If the player is local [islocalplayer] do XYZ to the healthbar. The statement then ends, There are no instructions in the code structure that states what to do if the player is not 'local'.

Comment: `healthBar.sizeDelta = new Vector2(((float)health / maxHeath) * maxHealthBarSize, healthBar.sizeDelta.y);
     ` is to resize the healthbar. This should only performed if the local player (= client) is damaged. Else the health bar would always update and have the wrong health.